# Etiqueta mark en jade no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, css, jade

Tengo el siguiente codigo que marca dinamicamente lo que escribe el usuario, notese que se utiliza html puro, pero cuando lo paso a jade no funciona

```js
var normal,
        destacado,
        texto,
        entrada;

    function inicializar() {
        
        normal = document.getElementById("normal");
        destacado = document.getElementById("destacado");
        texto = normal.innerText;
        entrada = document.getElementById("captureInput");
        entrada.addEventListener('input', actualizar);
    }

    function actualizar() {

        var porDestacar = entrada.value,
            pos = porDestacar.length;

        //Asignar la cantidad de caracteres ingresados desde el texto original
        destacado.innerText = texto.substr( 0, pos);
        //Asignar el resto
        normal.innerText = texto.substr( pos );

        //Coincide perfectamente?
        if (porDestacar === texto) {
            destacado.classList.add("completo");
        } else {
            destacado.classList.remove("completo");
        }
    }

    window.onload = inicializar();
```

```css
#normal {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    #destacado {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    #destacado.completo {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <p>
        <mark id="destacado"></mark><mark id="normal">no existe un rayo muy fuerte</mark>
    </p>
</div>
<input id="captureInput" type="text">
```

y cuando lo paso a jade ya no funciona

```
div(id="texto")
    p 
      mark(id="destacado") 
      mark(id="normal") no existe un rayo muy fuerte
    p
    textarea(type="text", id="captureInput", style="width:100%", cols="100", rows="3", placeholder="Escribe el texto de arriba en este cuadro", required)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error esta aquí:

```
window.onload = inicializar();// asignas el resultado de llamar a la funcion 'inicializar'
```

Estas llamando a la función `inicializar` y le estas asignando el resultado de esta a la función `window.onload`.

El problema se da, si el `script` es ejecutado antes de que el `HTML` se haya cargado, ya que los elementos que son requeridos (por ejemplo: `normal = document.getElementById("normal");`) aún no existen.

Solución:

```
window.onload = inicializar;// asignar la función para que se ejecute en el onload
```

Comment: el primer ejemplo que puse funciona, puedes hacer la prueba, mi problema es cuando lo paso a jade el html no funciona

Comment: me disculpo, tienes razon elimine () y funciono

Comment: y por que funciona mi ejemplo si esta con (), inicializar()?

Comment: si le dejas los paréntesis, la función se ejecuta inmediatamente (justo en esa linea), pero si le sacas los paréntesis, a `window.onload` le estas asignado una función, la cual sera ejecutada al terminar de cargarse la página.